# Is it not possible to check list items in Case Statement's condition?

Tags: oracle, case

I'm trying to check whether a list of items contain specific number in the condition part of a case statement in Oracle 10g. I get `ORA-00936: missing expression` error though. I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
Select case 'some_column_data' 
when in (1,2,3) then 'do_something' 
else 'do_something_else' end;
```

So, is there any way to accomplish what I'm intended to do, or checking whether value is in list iteratively in different `when` statements is the only solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using a "Searched CASE expression"

```
   CASE WHEN 'some_column_data' IN (1,2,3) 
        THEN 'do_something'
        ELSE 'do_something_else'
    END
```

See [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_case_sql_clause.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).