# Is there a way to create a list-like variable in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create multiple calculated fields off of a dataset. These calculations generally run the basic formula of

1. check if the room name is in a list
2. if yes: divide the square footage by a productivity rate
3. if no: null

As a more concrete example, the calculation for vacuuming an office looks like

```
CASE WHEN (room_name = 'OFFICE' OR room_name = 'CUBICLE' OR room_name = 'RECEPTION')
    THEN usable_sq_ft / 52
    ELSE null
END Vacuum
```

My problem is that there are many more room names that fall under office and many more tasks that need to be calculated and I don't want to type out that Boolean logic for each one. EDIT FOR CLARITY: In python I could just do something like

```
offices = ['office', 'cubicle', 'reception']
entrances = ['lobby', 'foyer', 'vestibule']
exercise = ['gym', 'weight_room']
if room_name in offices:
    <calculation>
else:
    null
```

Is there any way to write a list and test if a room name is in it in Oracle SQL?

Comment: An [`in` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html), perhaps? Or [`member of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html) a collection?

Comment: create a new table with the room type and scaling factor, and use an IN clause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634981/is-it-not-possible-to-check-list-items-in-case-statements-condition

Comment: The issue is that I have to define a list of room names for offices, a list for exercise rooms, a list for entrances, etc. In python I could define multiple lists at the same time and just reference one then another at will. I don't know how to create variables/objects like that in SQL though.

Comment: then include a column for "building type" or similar

Comment: SQL does not have variables. Perhaps you need a programming language such as for example PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

Then you can use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
CASE
WHEN room_name MEMBER OF string_list('OFFICE', 'CUBICLE', 'RECEPTION')
THEN usable_sq_ft / 52
END AS Vacuum
```

Or you can use `IN` with a table collection expression:

```sql
CASE
WHEN room_name IN (
       SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(string_list('OFFICE', 'CUBICLE', 'RECEPTION'))
     )
THEN usable_sq_ft / 52
END AS Vacuum
```

Or you can use `IN` with a sub-query:

```sql
CASE
WHEN room_name IN (
       SELECT 'OFFICE'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 'CUBICLE'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 'RECEPTION' FROM DUAL
     )
THEN usable_sq_ft / 52
END AS Vacuum
```

Or you can create another table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE room_types (
  room VARCHAR2(20),
  type VARCHAR2(20),
  vacuum_factor NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO room_types (room, type, vacuum_factor)
SELECT 'office',      'offices'   52 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cubicle',     'offices'   52 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'reception',   'offices'   52 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lobby',       'entrances' 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'foyer',       'entrances' 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'vestibule'    'entrances' 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'gym',         'exercise'  42 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'weight_room', 'exercise'  42 FROM DUAL;
```

Then use a sub-query:

```sql
usable_sq_ft / (SELECT vacuum_factor
                FROM   room_types
                WHERE  room = room_name 
                AND    type = 'office') AS Vacuum
```

Comment: Note that there are quite a few collection types defined in the DBMS_SQL package which come in handy sometimes, e.g. `TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` and `TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`. There are a number of others, for data types DATE, TIMESTAMP (of various flavors), BLOB, CLOB - all kinds of collections. [Check it out here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9)

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні Those all appear to be associative array collections (they use `TYPE ... IS TABLE OF ... INDEX BY ...`) which are PL/SQL data types and (except in limited circumstances in later versions) cannot be used in SQL statements. There are some built in `VARRAY` collection types defined in the `SYS` schema (i.e. `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`) and in other places but you cannot use the `MEMBER OF` operator with `VARRAY`s (you can use table collection expressions though).

Answer (score 0):

The first cte (room_names) containes sample data as I understood them from your question (just a guess).
You can then define your "lists" also as cte-s (room_classes) and (room_actions). Note that this is just a simulation of your python list related thingy.
I also suggest you to create those two cte-s as individual values (not lists of values) so you could join them to your room_names table using IN function. Here join is created
using INSTR function which is good only if all the values are complete and distinctive like in the code below. I don't know what your real data look like.
In this code I added a few actions too - so you can get different possibilities to calculate the value from your  question. Actions are defined list-like too and the note
as well as the suggestion above should be cosidered in the same way.
The code below gives you all the combinations of room classification and room actions as a result which can be selected, filtered and ordered as you wish.

```sql
WITH
    room_names AS
        (
            Select 1 "ROOM_ID", 'OFFICE'     "ROOM_NAME", 120 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ROOM_ID", 'CUBICLE'    "ROOM_NAME",  60 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3 "ROOM_ID", 'RECEPTION'  "ROOM_NAME", 350 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 4 "ROOM_ID", 'LOBBY'      "ROOM_NAME", 890 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 5 "ROOM_ID", 'FOYER'      "ROOM_NAME", 650 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 6 "ROOM_ID", 'VESTIBULE'  "ROOM_NAME", 480 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 7 "ROOM_ID", 'GYM'        "ROOM_NAME", 995 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 8 "ROOM_ID", 'WEIGHT_ROOM' "ROOM_NAME", 764 "USABLE_SQ_FT" From Dual 
        ),
    room_classes AS
        (
            Select 'Offices'    "ROOM_CLASS", 'OFFICE, CUBICLE, RECEPTION'  "MEMBERS", 'VACUUMING'                   "ACTIONS" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'Entrances'  "ROOM_CLASS", 'LOBBY, FOYER, VESTIBULE'     "MEMBERS", 'VACUUMING, SHINING'          "ACTIONS" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'Excercises' "ROOM_CLASS", 'GYM, WEIGHT_ROOM'            "MEMBERS", 'VACUUMING, WASHING, SHINING' "ACTIONS" From Dual 
        ),
    room_actions AS
        (
            Select 'VACUUMING'  "ROOM_ACTION", 52 "PRODUCTIVITY_RATE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'SHINING'    "ROOM_ACTION", 76 "PRODUCTIVITY_RATE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'WASHING'    "ROOM_ACTION", 62 "PRODUCTIVITY_RATE" From Dual 
        )
SELECT
    rc.ROOM_CLASS   "ROOM_CLASS",
    rn.ROOM_ID      "ROOM_ID",
    rn.ROOM_NAME    "ROOM_NAME",
    rn.USABLE_SQ_FT "USABLE_SQ_FT",
    ra.ROOM_ACTION  "ACTION",
    ra.PRODUCTIVITY_RATE "PRODUCTIVITY_RATE",
    CASE WHEN Nvl(ra.PRODUCTIVITY_RATE, 0) <> 0 THEN Round(rn.USABLE_SQ_FT / ra.PRODUCTIVITY_RATE, 2) ELSE 0 END "CALCULATED_VALUE"
FROM
    room_names rn
LEFT JOIN
    room_classes rc ON(INSTR(rc.MEMBERS, rn.ROOM_NAME) > 0)
LEFT JOIN
    room_actions ra ON(INSTR(rc.ACTIONS, ra.ROOM_ACTION) > 0)
ORDER BY
    rn.ROOM_ID
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  ROOM_CLASS    ROOM_ID ROOM_NAME   USABLE_SQ_FT ACTION    PRODUCTIVITY_RATE CALCULATED_VALUE
--  ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ --------- ----------------- ----------------
--  Offices             1 OFFICE               120 VACUUMING                52             2.31 
--  Offices             2 CUBICLE               60 VACUUMING                52             1.15 
--  Offices             3 RECEPTION            350 VACUUMING                52             6.73 
--  Entrances           4 LOBBY                890 VACUUMING                52            17.12 
--  Entrances           4 LOBBY                890 SHINING                  76            11.71 
--  Entrances           5 FOYER                650 VACUUMING                52             12.5 
--  Entrances           5 FOYER                650 SHINING                  76             8.55 
--  Entrances           6 VESTIBULE            480 VACUUMING                52             9.23 
--  Entrances           6 VESTIBULE            480 SHINING                  76             6.32 
--  Excercises          7 GYM                  995 VACUUMING                52            19.13 
--  Excercises          7 GYM                  995 SHINING                  76            13.09 
--  Excercises          7 GYM                  995 WASHING                  62            16.05 
--  Excercises          8 WEIGHT_ROOM          764 VACUUMING                52            14.69 
--  Excercises          8 WEIGHT_ROOM          764 SHINING                  76            10.05 
--  Excercises          8 WEIGHT_ROOM          764 WASHING                  62            12.32
```